# how to use require(chart.js) in codesandbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, chart.js, codesandbox

I was trying to do this in a codesandbox:

```
const Chart = require("chart.js");
  plot() {
    this.chart = new Chart(this.chartRef.current, {
     ..
          }
        ]
      }
    });
  }
```

However, I get an error on require:

```
Cannot find name 'require'.
```

and that `Chart is not a constructor`

I also tried replacing it with

```
import Chart from chart.js
```

but that also doesnt work. How can I fix my codesandbox? Here's a link

https://codesandbox.io/s/opur8?file=/src/Graph.tsx:2009-2333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load and register everything, try:

```
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
```

...which is short for...

```
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';
Chart.register(...registerables);
```

...which in turn is short for importing and registering every part individually. See the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html#bundlers-webpack-rollup-etc) for more examples.

Answer (score -1):

`Chart` class is exported as a named export.

Use: `import {Chart} from 'chart.js'`